# Unable to run coverage.py on QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.32.1-1

Tags: qgis, python, osgeo4w

I have recently installed QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.32.1-1 and attempted to run the following commands

```
C:\OSGeo4w\apps\Python39\python.exe -m coverage run test1.py param1 param2 param3 param4 param5

It will show 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\..........\test1.py, line 22, in <module>
    import qgis.analysis
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\analysis\__init__.py, line 26, in <module>
    from qgis.analysis import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _analysis: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.32.1-1

- Coverage version: 6.4.1
- Pytest version: 7.1.2
- Pytest-cov version: 3.0.0
- Python version: 3.9.5

But if I ran using this command

```
C:\OSGeo4w\apps\Python39\python.exe test1.py param1 param2 param3 param4 param5
```

There is no issue as shown above.

Lastly, if I ran the first command using python37 instead of python39 in the older version of  QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.10.1, it doesnt have this issue as well

```
D:\OSGeo4w\apps\Python37\python.exe -m coverage run test1.py param1 param2 param3 param4 param5
```

QGIS-OSGeo4W-3.10.1 dependencies

- Coverage version: 5.5.0
- Pytest version: 6.2.5
- Pytest-cov version: 2.12.1
- Python version: 3.7.0

Any help would be appreciated